# Error with multiple numpy.delete uses on array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

So, I was trying to understand the `numpy.delete` function, and I came up with something weird. Here's the program:

```
>>>import numpy as np  
>>>a = np.arange(10)  
>>> a  
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9])  
>>> a[5]  
5  
>>> a=np.delete(a,[a[5]])  
>>> a  
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9])  #so far so good  
>>> a[6]  
7  
>>> a=np.delete(a,[a[6]])  
>>> a  
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9])
```

So... When I put `a=np.delete(a,[a[6]])`, it should be expected to remove the number `7` from the array, right? Why was it the number `8` (the term `a[7]`) from the array) removed instead of the expected `a[6]`?
I also noticed that when I try to remove the `a[0]`(=0) from the array after the first delete, I just can't. It always removes one term ahead. Any Idea how do I remove  it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument should be the **index** of the element you want to delete, not the element itself.

```
a=np.delete(a,6)
```

In the first case, it only worked because a[5] happened to equal 5, so the index and the value were the same.

When you have:

```
a=np.delete(a,[a[6]])
```

You are deleting the 7th element since a[6] = 7 there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new to this function and thought the a[i] was the  parameter. But it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: `np.delete` is not the same as list `remove`.